# Why doesn't the non-greedy (minimum match) work in regex?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I read some tips, if add `?` can match the non-greedy regex like,

```
x = "a (b) c (d) e"
re.search(r"\(.*?\)", x).group()
>>> '(b)'
```

why my code cannot work?

```
import re
item = "等" #item is variable 
content = "大数据，人工智能,云计算：数字孪生、5G，物联网和区块链等新一代数字技术应用"
res = re.search(r'(?<=[，,：、，])(.*?)(?=' + item + ')', content).group()
print(res)
```

I want to find the content in the middle of any cloest symbols(left) and `item`(right), and I hope the res like

```
物联网和区块链
```

but it return long one, non-greedy didn't work, why?

Comment: Because `.` matches all of the `，,：、，` chars. Replace it with a negated character class if none should appear on the way from the punctuation chars to the `item`, i.e. `[^，,：、，]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks lot, it works now! p.s the regex like, ' r'[^，,：、，]*(?=' + item + ')' '

Comment: Or, better, `re.search(fr'[，,：、，]([^，,：、，]*?){re.escape(item)}', content)`, then grab `.group(1)`.

Comment: @Hi Wiktor, I have a question, if the start is some words, for example t1,t2, not single symbols, how to correct it? I mean where can I add ^ to  (t1|t2)?

Comment: `re.search(fr'(?:t1|t2)((?:(?!t1|t2).)*?){re.escape(item)}', content)`, then grab `.group(1)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry to bother you again, thanks for your help at first! may I ask a similar question, actually I want to find the sub-string, start with t1 or t2(not include) , to the end of string, and non-greedy(make the sub-string shortest), I want to follow your idea  `fr'(?:t1|t2)((?:(?!t1|t2).)*?)'` but not sucessful...any suggestion is helpful for me!

Comment: Just remove `?` at the end. `r'(?:t1|t2)((?:(?!t1|t2).)*)'`